# Inconsistencies in GreenFunction versus DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I am wondering why  this code

```
GreenFunction[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] -
 Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, True]}, 
u[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity}, t, {y, s}]
```

returns something correct,

[image]

whereas this one

```
 DSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity}, t]
```

returns unevaluated.

> This is probably a silly question but it may reflect some level of inconsistency in the notation?

PS: incidentally, this one works,

```
    GreenFunction[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, t, {y, s}]
```

but not this one (!)

```
GreenFunction[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, t], {x, -1, 1}, t, {y, s}]
```

Comment: GreenFunction returns a special particular solution whereas your DSolve[...] tries to find a general homogenous solution.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for the clarification: would you know how to get `DSolve` to provide any solution to this specific problem?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Usually one takes GreenFunction to solve an inhomogenous pde, but your's is homogenous.

Comment: So far I tried separation of variables  `u[x,t]=T[t] X[x]` but didn't get the solution.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann no worries. I was just wondering if you knew off-hand why my syntax was wrong.

Comment: The correct syntax should be `DSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == 0, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, True] }, u[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity},
  t]` I think.

Comment: I am surprised your `DSolve` doesn't give you zero, since you only have zeros there.  This works, though. `DSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] == 0, 
  u[0, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == u0, u[a, t] == 0}, u[x, t], {x, t}]`.  If you use infinity for `a` you just get zero.